# How to display external website in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to connect an URL to a menuSubItem in sidebarMenu on the left so if I click on that item, it will display webpage in the right blank page. I've tried `tags$iframe` or simply put `a(href="")` in UI but both failed. Below is my sample code in UI.

````
```
sidebar<- dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
          menuItem("Homepage", tabName = "homepage", icon = icon("home")),
          menuItem("Liability Distribution", tabName = "liab_dist",
                   menuSubItem("Google", tabName = "Google", icon = icon("angle-right")))))
````

```
body<-dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    #Google
    tabItem(tabName = "Google", 
            fluidRow(
              tags$iframe(
                seamless = "seamless",
                src = "http://google.com",
                height = 800, width = 1400)))))
```

Comment: Please show an intended and unintended result or output.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code - there's just two caveats when dealing with iframes: 1.) RStudio does not load external resources - guess it's for security. But as soon as you run your shiny app, you get an output like this: `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7572`. When you paste `http:...` into a new tab in Chrome (or Firefox or your favorite browser), you'll get some content *in most cases*. Google is an exception (and there are many more) as 2.) some websites that tell the browser to not display them in an iframe (when you go to google.com with devtools open in Chrome (or again: Firefox or your favorite), you'll see `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN` as response header. So you're out of luck here - but I'd suggest trying with your personal blog or some page you know allows for iFrames. As soon as you open in anything but the Shiny preview of RStudio, you most likely get a result.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! I solved the issue since I realized I made a very stupid question. I should put png in www folder.